How to Retrieve Transaction Data for a Specific Cosmos Address When API Returns No Transactions?
I'm attempting to retrieve transaction data for a specific address on the Cosmos blockchain using Python and aiohttp. The address in question shows 61 transactions on Mintscan, but when querying the blockchain's API, it returns no transactions. Here's my current code:
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch_transactions_for_address(node_url, address):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        url = f"{node_url}/cosmos/tx/v1beta1/txs?events=message.sender='{address}'&events=tx.height=200000"
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            print(f"Response Status: {response.status}")
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                transactions = data['tx_responses']
                return len(transactions)
            else:
                response_text = await response.text()
                print(f"Failed to fetch data: {response_text}")
                raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch data: {response.status}")

async def main():
    node_url = "https://cosmos-rest.publicnode.com"
    address = "cosmos1hcaq68m5krxuppd8xnqnrm4uf2gudkmhns5d6n"
    try:
        transaction_count = await fetch_transactions_for_address(node_url, address)
        print(f"Number of transactions for the address: {transaction_count}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

How can I adjust my script or approach to correctly retrieve the 61 transactions shown on Mintscan   for this address?

You should probably use params, it may be encoding the URL: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls

What is the output that you are getting currently?
